# Payara5 wmq.jmsra connection failure with MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection

Tags: ibm-mq, connection-pooling, payara

I installed wmq.jmsra Resource adapter to Payara 5.2022.5 application server. I created a connector connection pool.

```
./asadmin create-connector-connection-pool --raname wmq.jmsra --connectiondefinition javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --transactionsupport XATransaction --property transportType=CLIENT:queueManager=QMANAGER:hostName=HOSTIP:port=PORT:channel=CHANNEL:username=USER:password=PASSWORD:applicationName=APPNAME wmq.jmsra-pool

./asadmin create-connector-resource --poolname wmq.jmsra-pool jms/JmsConnectionFactory
```

Everything was working, I was debugging the application via remote. Time to time, I redeploy my application which uses the connection pool. All of a sudden, Payara started to throw the following exception. It was interesting because 5 minutes before it worked.

I restart queue manager, removed pool definition, undeployed wmq.jmsra and configured it all over again. Nothing is changed. Restarted the domain.

It says it can't find the com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP class however I can see it in the jmqi jar file of the wmq.jmsra application that is deployed.

Later I restarted everything, even my local computer, and worked but started to fail after a while.

Do anyone have similar issues?

```
[2023-06-07T12:46:33.739+0300] [Payara 5.2022.5] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=346 _ThreadName=Thread-39] [timeMillis: 1686131193739] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection.
An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail.
See the linked exception for details of the failure.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:184)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedJMSConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:402)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnectionInternal(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:252)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:225)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:201)
    at com.heirloomcomputing.ecs.mqi.jms.module.StandardJMSModule.createConnection(StandardJMSModule.java:206)
    at com.heirloomcomputing.ecs.mqi.jms.module.StandardJMSModule.obtainConnection(StandardJMSModule.java:437)
    at com.heirloomcomputing.ecs.mqi.jms.JMSConnectionManager.mqConnect(JMSConnectionManager.java:61)
    at com.heirloomcomputing.ecs.mqi.MQIConnectionManagerAbstract.createConnection(MQIConnectionManagerAbstract.java:221)
    at com.heirloomcomputing.ecs.mqi.MQIConnectionManagerAbstract.mqConnect(MQIConnectionManagerAbstract.java:280)
    ......
    at com.heirloomcomputing.etp.transaction.services.IntervalControl$1.run(IntervalControl.java:390)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:288)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1532)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:957)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:236)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:388)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedJMSConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1209)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:100)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.createResource(ConnectorAllocator.java:184)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:919)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:169)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:162)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:655)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionImpl.<init>(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:212)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.createResource(ConnectorAllocator.java:164)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
See the linked exception for further information.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:334)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:172)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8023)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:385)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:137)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:134)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment,int)],3=Class.getConstructor0]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:855)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:699)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:164)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment,int)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:761)
    ... 50 more
]]
```

I am trying to create JMS connection pool with wmq.jmsra resource adapter at Payara 5.

Comment: Please check whether you have embedded mq jar file(s) into your application (in addition to having installed it to the application server). If so, please remove the embedded jar and give this a try.

Comment: Thank you @NineFriends , I forgot to remove mq client jars from the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if MQ jar's are embedded into the application in addition to having installed them to the application server.